# Button switch input signal reading was higher than VDD value at some point

Tags: signal, oscilloscope

I was monitoring a signal output from a button during debouncing on my oscilloscope and surprisingly as you can see in the image, the signal peaked at 5.92 volts and then went back to the VDD value which is around 5 volts.

Why and how did the signal exceed its VDD value at some point?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/158004/2028

Comment: One must treat these fast wave shapes with some scepticism. Probes often add artifacts that may only exist while probing, because of added capacitance and inductance. Does your probe have a GND clip with a long wire? Try it with a very short wire, and see if the transient shape differs.

Comment: it could be a transmission-line effect,  how is the circuit pysically constructed?

Answer (score 0):

It could be an artifact, it could be you have a spike due to inductance on the switched line, or it could be a reflection.

We'd need a circuit diagram and picture of the physical setup to be sure.  You could see if adding a series resistor (to limit current flow during state change) improves matters.